# Not able to connect remote debugger in React native in mac for iOS app?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to debug using chrome.
I have added React Native Tool extension in VSCode, but getting error as:

```
[Error] Error: Unable to find plist file to configure debugging
```

when I am checking on chrome using http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/ still not able to connect debugger.

I am new to react native please suggest if need more information for this issue

Answer (score 2):

Citing the first paragraph from the react-native's site, regarding [Chrome Debugging](https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging#chrome-developer-tools)

> To debug the JavaScript code in Chrome, select "Debug JS Remotely" from the Developer Menu. This will open a new tab at http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui.

So technically, in the `iOS simulator`, you have to cast the following combination `ctrl + cmd + z`, and tap on the `Debug JS Remotely` field, which will further open the debugger hosted on the following address `http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui`

As an workaround, on the same react-native site, there's a page where is explained how to debug the app via a [standalone developer tool](http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui), which is installed as an `npm package`.

All you have to do is to install the package through `npm` or `yarn` (choose the package manager which you like the most :] )

```
* the same react-native site recommends to install it globally

npm install -g react-devtools

yarn add global react-devtools
```

And after installing the package just type in the terminal the following command to open the devtools

```
react-devtools
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the localhost value with your internal ip in the browser url of devtools.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8081/debugger-ui/
```

Answer (score 0):

give a try to complete suit for react native debugging, performance analysis along with latest react-devtools

[Flipper](https://fbflipper.com/docs/getting-started/index)

now it is part of react-native-cli but you can configure in your existing react native version by following

[Android Setup](https://fbflipper.com/docs/getting-started/android-native)

[iOS Setup](https://fbflipper.com/docs/getting-started/ios-native)