# Could not debug. Unable to find plist file to configure debugging in react native?

Tags: ios, react-native

i have app in react native which is running fine with `react-native run-ios` but when i try to debug it shows "Could not debug. Unable to find plist file to configure debugging" error for debugger.

I am using extension react native tool for debugging. Debugging is working fine in android but getting issue on IOS.

Please suggest if more information is required to solve this issue?

Thank you for help

Comment: can you post a stacktrace?

Comment: "Debugging is working fine in android but getting issue only in Android." where are you having this problem. Android or iOS?

Comment: could this help? https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-react-native/issues/718

Comment: Could you check your `/YOUR_APP_DIR/ios/YOUR_APP_NAME/` if `Info.plist` is there? if  it's there, the update your tool config debugging.

Answer (score 2):

(**Disclaimer**: I got the same error **in iOS**. As is not clear in which OS are you having the problem, I will put my grain of sand here.)

In my particular case, it was caused because I removed `localhost` entry from `NSAppTransportSecurity` in `Info.plist`. This is required for development/debugging.

Here is how this section should look like:

```xml
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Comment: how am i so stupid lol, two weeks trying to figure it out what i did to ruin the ios build, and i forgot i change those lines to upload my app to the app store, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found an similar request here... maybe this solve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63747767/1256697

So make sure, that

1. the Debugger (`Google-Chrome Browser` at http://localhost:8081:debugger-ui or `react-devtools`) and is up and running
2. You connect your device / simulator with the Debugger via Developer-Menu (on IOS Simulator it's `ctrl + cmd + z`, on hardware devices.. shake the device)
3. Choose `Debug JS Remotely`

If that's not the solution, please provide more information how do you start the debugging-process, which IDE you use (like XCode, VSCode, IntelliJ...).